# Django Model Inheritance to multiple apps

Tags: django, inheritance, model

```
class People(models.Model):

    # Utility Fields - auto fill

    # Timestamp

    # Base Fields
    
    # Methods, e.g save, get_absolute_url

    class Meta:
          abstract = True
```

- App clients: inherit from People model + its own Fields
- App vendors: inherit from People model + its own Fields

Questions

- Q1: Where should I place the code for the People model, since I want to use it for more than 2 apps?
- Q2: Is this practice acceptable?
- Q3: Will it work in a production environment efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1: Where should I place the code for the People model, since I want to use it for more than 2 apps?**

Just create a third app for abstract models. It's fine.

**Q2: Is this practice acceptable?**

Yes. `abstract = True` is just intended for this.

**Q3: Will it work in a production environment efficiently?**

Yes, also, `abstract = True` does not create new db tables or relations, is just code.